# Screen reader accessibility for password-like text

Tags: html, css, accessibility

In some situations you want to render an alphanumeric code or other such text which should be reproduced elsewhere exactly, where e.g. the case of each character is important. You may markup each character separately and apply styles to more easily distinguish `O0`, `1Il`, etc.

However, how would a screen reader or similar accessibility tool read this? Ideally I'd want this to be read as something like "zero, uppercase em, lowecase ee". It should not say e.g. "zero, me", nor simply "zero, em, ee".

```html
<span class="token"><!--
  --><span class="token-d">0</span><!--
  --><span class="token-u">M</span><!--
  --><span class="token-l">e</span><!--
--></span>
```

Comment: The question is being discussed [in Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385269).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `aria-label`:

```html
<span aria-label="Uppercase A">A</span><!--
--><span aria-label="Lowercase l">l</span><!--
--><span aria-label="3">3</span><!--
--><span aria-label="lowercase x">x</span>
```

Comment: That's a good start but you'd have to tweak it a bit since `aria-label` is sometimes not honored for non-semantic elements (such as `<div>` and `<span>`).  See https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support